# loop a list using a jquery - carousel effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, carousel

I'm trying to loop a list making a carousel effect. I think it should know first the counts of all the list so it can do math. then it can do something like this. If it add on the other side it will remove something on the other side. So if I remove the first list item it will add the the last item.

```
$(function() {

    $('#up').mouseenter(goUp);
    $('#down').mouseenter(goDown);

    function goUp() {
        $('#list').last('li').remove;
        $('#list').first('li').append('put the first item here')
    }


    function goDown() {
        $('#list').first('li').remove;
        $('#list').last('li').append('put the first item here')
    }   

}

<a id="up">+</a>
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>

</ul>

<a id="down">-</a>
```

Comment: You have a bunch of errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of errors there and I think your logic is wrong. You want to use a `.current` class and `hide()` or `show()` the items. Something like this should work.

```
$items.hide().first().addClass('cur').show();

var actions = {
    getCurIdx: function(){ 
        return $items.filter('.cur').index(); 
    },
    goTo: function(idx){
        // Something like...
        $items
       .removeClass('cur').hide()
       .eq(idx).addClass('cur').show();
    },
    next: function(){ 
        var _idx = actions.getCurIdx(); 
        if(_idx < $items.length) { 
            actions.goTo(_idx+1); 
        } else {
            actions.goTo(0); // Go first
        }
    },
    prev: function(){ 
        var _idx = actions.getCurIdx(); 
        if(_idx >= 0) { 
            actions.goTo(_idx-1); 
        } else {
            actions.goTo($items.length-1); // Go last
        }
    }
};

$next.click(function(){ actions.next(); });
$prev.click(function(){ actions.prev(); });
```

Comment: Incorrect, remove doesn't actually delete the element, it just disconnects it from the DOM. It is maintained in memory of the jQuery object you selected it until that object is descoped. Once it is descoped it is put in the queue for GC. This means if you capture it in a local variable it is kept in scope and you can put it back into the DOM.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I edited the answer. I usually use `detach()` for that because it also keeps events associated to that object. Then again, I don't think `remove()` is the right approach in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems, first the `last` and `first` methods don't work the way you're thinking, you don't pass a selector to them ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/last/)) so what you're actually doing is finding the last element in the matched selector of `#list`. What you want to be using is the `:last` selector ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)) (and `:first`), changing your selectors to.

Next `remove` is a method not a property, so you are missing some brackets. Also `remove` will return the jQuery object that you were working against so you can reposition it in the DOM.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slace/PrxdA/) that implements what you want. It uses the `before` and `after` methods to insert the new item correctly in the DOM.